# Elementary theorems in number theory which need analytical methods (analysis)

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

A well known theorem of Dirichlet says: if $a,b$ are relatively prime positive integers, then there are infinitely many primes of the form $an+b$.

The original proof by Dirichlet (possibly) uses analytical methods. Also, in special cases, such as for $a=4$ and $b=1$ or $3$, the theorem can be proved in elementary fashion, without using analysis.

However, I heard, that there is no proof of Dirichlet theorem which avoids analysis.

Another interesting theorem in number theory is *"$n!$ is never a perfect square"* whose proof uses again analytical methods ([see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/n-is-never-a-perfect-square-if-n-geq2-is-there-a-proof-of-this-that-doesn)).

**Question.** What are the other theorems in number theory (other than F.L.T) which are easy to state, but whose proof necessarily depends on analytical methods?

Comment: I think that Minkowski's theorem deal with this matter!

Comment: The proof of $n!$ never being a perfect square doesn't require analysis. Bertrand's postulate (what is meant by Chebyshev's theorem) has an elementary proof [in this paper](https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/pdf/bertrand.pdf) (by Erdös, section $2$). Dirichlet's theorem for primes of the form $nk+1$ can be easily proved using cyclotomic polynomials without analysis (proofs can be found in many places, e.g. [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-781-theory-of-numbers-spring-2012/lecture-notes/MIT18_781S12_lec12.pdf)).

Comment: I don't know Minkowski's "theorem" in number theory. Can you state?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_of_numbers