# Factorials and their perfect squares

Tags: number-theory, factorial

How many positive factorials are also perfect Squares. So for example $1!=1=1^2$. How many others exist other than 1?

Is there any way to prove this?

Comment: Also useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/n-is-never-a-perfect-square-if-n-geq2-is-there-a-proof-of-this-that-doesn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**

Bertrand's postulate(in actuality a theorem) states that for every prime $p$, there exists another prime number between $p$ and $2p$.
This means that $\forall n>1, n!$ will always have a single power of some prime number(s).

For any positive integer $n\ge 2$, there exists a prime $p$ such that $\frac{n}{2}<p\le n$ This implies that $p\mid n!$. For $n\ge 5, p^2>n$. So if $n!$ has unique prime factorization $p_1^{k_1} \cdot p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_r^{k_r} $, then the exponent of $p$ must be $1$. Since perfect squares must have even exponents in their prime factorizations, we know $n!$ cannot be a perfect square for $n \ge 5$.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: No, there will be 2. $0!$ and $1!$. I'll leave it for you to see why.

Comment: While this is just a hint, I would recommend expanding your answer a bit, as the OP may not be very familiar with this.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: How's that?

Comment: @yagnapatel Thank you!

Comment: What is $q$ ? Furthermore, why do you explicitely mention that $n!$ will have a unique prime factorization ?

Comment: @Peter: See my edit.

Comment: And also, this question is a possible duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12544/can-n-be-a-perfect-square-when-n-is-an-integer-greater-than-1?lq=1.