# Occurrence (parity) of primes in $n!$

Tags: number-theory

It is known that [$n!$ can not be a perfect square for $n\geq 1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12544/can-n-be-a-perfect-square-when-n-is-an-integer-greater-than-1) This means that in the prime decomposition of $n!$, one of the prime occurs odd number of times. This leads to following two questions:

**1.** Consider largest prime $p$, which is $\leq n$. Then in $n!$ does $p$ occurs odd number of times?

In $5!=2^3.3.5$, *each* prime occurs odd number of times.

**2.** Are there infinitely many integers $n$ such that *each* prime in $n!$ occurs odd number of times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. By Bertrand's postulate, there is always a prime $p$ between $\frac{n}{2}$ and $n$, so $p$ occurs exactly one time in the decomposition of $n!$.
2. No. By prime number theorem we can prove that for any (strictly) positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists $n_0$ such that $\forall n > n_0$, there is prime $p$ such that $n < p < (1+\epsilon )n$.

   Consider $m = \frac{n}{3}$ and $\epsilon = 0.5$, there is $n_0$ such that $\forall m > n_0$, there is prime $p$ such that $\frac{n}{3} = m < p < (1+\epsilon )m = \frac{n}{2}$. So the prime $p$ occurs exactly $2$ times in the decomposition of $n!$.

**EDIT**: In fact $n = 5$ is the **only** number such that every prime factor of $n!$ occurs an odd number of times. For all $n \geqslant 22$ there is always a prime $p$ between $\frac{n}{3}$ and $\frac{n}{2}$ ($\frac{n}{3} < p <\frac{n}{2}$) so that $p$ occurs exactly $2$ times in the decomposition of $n!$. And we can verify that no number smaller than $22$ has the property.

Answer (score 1):

part 1, yes, Bertrand's

part 2, no, take $n$ large, by estimates on [prime gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) that have actually been proved there is a prime $p > 3$ with
 $$ \frac{n}{3} < p < \frac{n}{2}.  $$ Then
$$ 2 < \frac{n}{p} < 3 $$ and
$$  \frac{n}{p^2} < 1. $$
By [Legendre's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula), $\nu_p n! = 2.$