# Factorial can never be a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that $n!$ can never be a perfect square for $n>1$

I have no idea on how to begin this problem.(I don't want to use Bertrand's theorem as it is beyond the level of the exam I have to take now.)

Comment: what other properties do you know ?

Comment: I doubt that we can prove the claim without Betrand's postulate.

Comment: See [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165984/401264) on an old question

Comment: Specifically I know most of pre college stuff

Comment: how about the number of 2's in the factorization ? if you know that you can rule things out ...