# CFL grammer questions

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

I'm preparing to my test and I have 2 question in past test with no answers.
Could you help me?

1. Prove or disprove the following claim. The language $$L=\{a^n\mid n!=k^2, k\ge 0\}$$ is a CFL.

I now that is not true, but I'm struggling prove it. I'm always stuck on the pumping lemma by choosing the right word.

2.Given a Content Free Language $L$ and its grammar $G$. Write a CFG $G’$ for a new
language: $$\operatorname{AddLetter}(L)=\{uxv\mid x \in \Sigma,  u,v \in \Sigma^*, u,v\in L\}\,.$$

I tried to get a correct grammar, but I don't know what I need to do with the $L$ language - I have no clue of its alphabet.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. When asking questions, people will respond more positively if you: list your efforts and thoughts and type up your question using MathJax instead of linking images. Please consider editing your question.

Comment: @Integrand thank you! I did it

Comment: To get proper spacing for the *such that* stroke use `\mid` rather than `|`. Curly braces are formatting symbols for MathJax; to get them to display, use `\{` and `\}`.

Comment: Did you mean $n \not= k^2$ instead of $n! = k^2$?

Comment: Next question: CFL speling questions?

Answer (score 1):

That first question is more about number theory than about formal languages and automata: $n!$ is [never a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12544/can-n-be-a-perfect-square-when-n-is-an-integer-greater-than-1) if $n\ge 2$, so $L=\{\varepsilon,a\}$, which is even a regular language.

> **Added:** J.-E. Pin has pointed out that the original pure text version, which I’d not seen, is ambiguous, and that the OP may well have intended $L$ to be the set $a^n$ such that $n$ is not the perfect square of any non-negative integer. If that’s the case, then of course the above answer is irrelevant, and it turns out that $L$ is not context-free.

> One way to prove this is to apply [Parikh’s theorem](https://planetmath.org/parikhstheorem), which implies that a language over a one-letter alphabet is context-free if and only if it is regular. It is easy to use the pumping lemma for regular languages to show that $L$ is not regular. (It is perhaps even easier to use the pumping lemma for regular languages to show that $\{a\}^*\setminus L=\left\{a^{k^2}:k\ge 0\right\}$ is not regular and then use the fact that regular languages are closed under complementation.)

For the second question I think that you may assume that $\Sigma$ is the alphabet for both languages; $\operatorname{AddLetter}(L)$ is simply the set of words over $\Sigma$ that can be decomposed as $uxv$, where $u$ and $v$ are in $L$, and $x$ is any single character in the alphabet $\Sigma$. If $S$ is the initial non-terminal of $G$, give $G'$ a new initial symbol $S'$; then for each $x\in\Sigma$ the grammar $G'$ will have a production $S'\to \_x\_$, where I’ll leave it to you to fill in the two blanks.

Comment: If you look carefully at the first version of the question, it seems that the OP meant $n \not= k^2$ instead of $n! = k^2$. I wait for your opinion to edit the question.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: I think that you may well be right, especially since the current version really does strike me as rather unreasonable; it’s unfortunate that the OP posted the wrong image. I’m not sure, though, whether it’s better to go ahead and edit it and leave an explanatory comment, or for now just to post a comment asking what was intended. I’d probably do the latter, but I’m willing to go along with either.